# ErrorMessage does not work in Validation Application Block 6

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem with VAB 6 when I use Attribute like below

```
[NotNullValidator(ErrorMessage="Name must be not null")]
[StringLengthValidator(1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 5,RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,ErrorMessage="Length Error")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

`@Html.ValidationSummary()` shows me default Error messages not as specified

> Name must be not null >> **The value cannot be null**
>
> Length Error >> **The length of the value must fall within the range
>   "1" (Inclusive) - "5" (Inclusive)**

Why VAB 6 force me with default messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong qualifier for the **NotNullValidator** attribute.  Try this instead:

```
[NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate="Name must be not null")]
```

See [this page on the NotNullValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647731.aspx) for more details.